# Setting CGO_CFLAGS persistently in a Go package?

Tags: go

My Go package includes a .c file that uses a library which needs certain CFLAGS set.  On the command line to "go install" I can specify `CGO_CFLAGS` with the needed flags, and everything works.  However, I would like to make it so that someone can "go get" my package and build it without passing any extra command line arguments.

Does the Go packaging system provide a place where I could put some config like this, to specify some arguments that are always needed when `go install`ing a package?

(I'm aware of doing `#cgo CFLAGS:` directives in Go source files, but recall that in my package I have a .c source file so need the CGO_CFLAGS setting to the overall build process)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*cgo* extracts your *#cgo CFLAGS:* to an environment variable during build (pass "-x" flag to *go build*). If you *go install -x*  you see that it honors your cflags/ldflags specified in your Go library. In other words, it should work to just specify them in your Go files.

Comment: @Erikw thanks, I had somehow got the idea that the options in my .go files weren't getting applied to .c files, but you're quite right that they are.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use any of your C functions you still have to mix some cgo into your .go files, in those files just declare your flags, for example:

test.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -DTEST
#include <stdio.h>
extern void ACFunction();
*/
import "C"

//export AGoFunction
func AGoFunction() {
        fmt.Println("AGoFunction()")
}

func main() {
        C.ACFunction()
}
```

test.c:

```
#include "_cgo_export.h"
void ACFunction() {
#ifdef TEST
        printf("ACFunction()\n");
#endif
        AGoFunction();
}
```

Putting these in the same directory will make `go build` pickup the flags defined in test.go and apply them when building test.c.

Comment: Just to note, this works even without including `_cgo_export.h` so long as you don't call `AGoFunction`. Go passes CFLAGS to the compiler when compiling any c files in the current package directory.